# How to Copy Paste ECW maps together?

Tags: arcgis-pro, ecw

I have found previous threads but they are different enough to not be very useful to me.

I have the pages of a reference atlas for a city that were photo scanned and then placed in ECW files.

There are hundreds of pages and therefore hundreds of ECW files.

I would like to place all of these images side by side so that I could see all pages at once in the form of a map.

In one file.

Here are screen shots as an example.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have ArcGIS pro through my employer. How do I combine these images? Is there a way that I could copy paste similarly to combining images in paint 3D?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking, wouldn't 100's of pages "side by side" be completely unmanageable? Also you don't discuss what you want done with the street index? Old maps are often georeferenced so they mosaicked together, but such maps would not have most of the image taken up with street indices, they are the map. If you want the maps to reference a coordinate space then you need to create control points for each map and georeference them, but you'll need to mask out the index and inset maps. You have a non-trivial nighmare ahead of you...

Comment: @Hornbydd It is more so dozens and I shouldn't have hyperbolized so much, but... these are the indexes at the beginning of each "atlas" the red dividing lines refer to the page of which a zoomed in hyper local map can be located.

As it stands we have an ECW file for each of these maps but it is cumbersome to constantly flip and open these files. 

It would be extremely helpful to have just one or even a few ECW files with these maps combined and arranged.

Comment: @Hornbydd I would also like to crop the map out as well since you bring it up.

Comment: Do you really need them to be in one file, or just to be able to manage them all together as though they were a single map layer?  If the latter (and if you have a Standard license), then you should look into the 'Mosaic' tools.  You can create a single mosaic raster layer that it composed of multiple raster images.  you can even use the mosaic tools to define which parts of each image should be excluded (such as the text portions that you don't want to see).  The map then displays the mosaic as a single seamless raster...

Comment: ... for starters, see:  https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/imagery/creating-mosaic-datasets-wf.htm  and https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.9/tool-reference/data-management/add-rasters-to-mosaic-dataset.htm .   Using mosaics, the GIS doesn't need to load up one enormous unmanagable dataset.  It only needs to load up the portions that are currently on screen.  It will also create 'overviews' (like pyramids) of the mosaic for viewing larger areas when zoomed out.  So again, if viewing the entire dataset (zoomed out), it only needs to load the overview for that zoom level.

Comment: This is likely what I need. Thank you so much. I will get started on it.